# How to remove/solve C++ function template instantiation notes/warnings

Tags: c++, templates

I'm using libigl for my C++ project. The library makes the compiler (MSVC Windows 10) displays messages like:

```
C:\...\libigl\include\igl\unique_rows.cpp(57): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::operator !=<Derived>(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Block<Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,1,-1,false>
        ]
```

Is there a way to remove these messages? They don't stop the compilation.

I notice errors like this appear when using template functions like the following.

```cpp
#include <igl/cotmatrix.h>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
void function_test(const Eigen::MatrixXd &vertices, const Eigen::MatrixXi &faces)
{
   Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> cotangents;
   igl::cotmatrix(vertices, faces, cotangents); // warning/note is thrown here
}
```

I feel like the compiler wants `igl::cotmatrix<...>(vertices, faces, cotangents)`. But writing out the types inside the `<...>` is pretty cumbersome since the compiler can figure them out on its own.

Here is the complete compilation log.

```
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hw3.dir/main.cpp.obj
main.cpp
C:\Users\Song\Documents\UDEM\ift6113\hw\ift6113_2020\libigl\include\igl\parallel
_for.h(133): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
C:\Users\Song\Documents\UDEM\ift6113\hw\ift6113_2020\libigl\include\igl\parallel
_for.h(109): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool igl::p
arallel_for<Index,igl::parallel_for::<lambda_bf61686955a08140b85787f279539468>,i
gl::parallel_for::<lambda_19b8090a242a0d3b3af69d3d9111a171>,igl::parallel_for::<
lambda_bf61686955a08140b85787f279539468>>(const Index,const PreFunctionType &,co
nst FunctionType &,const AccumFunctionType &,const size_t)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Index=int,
            PreFunctionType=igl::parallel_for::<lambda_bf61686955a08140b85787f27
9539468>,
            FunctionType=igl::parallel_for::<lambda_19b8090a242a0d3b3af69d3d9111
a171>,
            AccumFunctionType=igl::parallel_for::<lambda_bf61686955a08140b85787f
279539468>
        ]
C:\Users\Song\Documents\UDEM\ift6113\hw\ift6113_2020\libigl\include\igl\squared_
edge_lengths.cpp(43): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bo
ol igl::parallel_for<int,igl::squared_edge_lengths::<lambda_302a67c1d9096b57535f
5b0d969f13ce>>(const Index,const FunctionType &,const size_t)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Index=int,
            FunctionType=igl::squared_edge_lengths::<lambda_302a67c1d9096b57535f
5b0d969f13ce>
        ]
C:\Users\Song\Documents\UDEM\ift6113\hw\ift6113_2020\libigl\include\igl\cotmatri
x_entries.cpp(41): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void
igl::squared_edge_lengths<Derived,Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,Eigen::Matrix
<double,-1,3,0,-1,3>>(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &,const Eigen::MatrixBase
<Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>> &,Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double
,-1,3,0,-1,3>> &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>
        ]
C:\Users\Song\Documents\UDEM\ift6113\hw\ift6113_2020\libigl\include\igl\cotmatri
x.cpp(60): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void igl::cot
matrix_entries<Derived,Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,
-1,0,-1,-1>>(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &,const Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::M
atrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>> &,Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived> &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>
        ]
C:\Users\Song\Documents\UDEM\ift6113\hw\ift6113_2020\stackoverflow\main.cpp(7):
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void igl::cotmatrix<Deri
ved,Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>,double>(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> &,
const Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<int,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>> &,Eigen::SparseMatrix<
double,0,int> &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            Derived=Eigen::Matrix<double,-1,-1,0,-1,-1>
        ]
[100%] Linking CXX executable hw3.exe
[100%] Built target hw3
```

Comment: These messages are information messages which serve to explain other messages, which are error or warning messages. In order to remove information messages you need to make sure your code generates no errors or warnings. It would be great if you could also post these error or warning messages. These have the words `error` or `warning` in them.

Comment: the message you posted is only a fragment, its a "note" that provides additional information for the previous "warning" or "error". Please include the complete message in the question.

Comment: Very often, these additionnal messages are as much helpful as the error itself as they are closer to your code. In my opinion, it would be nice if it was possble to see them in the error windows too.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. and others, I have attached the full compilation log.

Comment: You can disable compiler warnings or open a bug against libigl, it's a problem in their code.